# internal server error. Trying to delete an element from array in mlab with angular and mongoose

Tags: angular, mongoose, mlab

i want to delete an element out of the array opmerkingen but it is giving me the 500 internal server error that says cannot read property 'findbyidandremove' or undefined

Below you see the code for deleting an element in the database but that is not working. I think my query is wrong but i don't know how to solve it.

```
router.delete("/webapptaak/topics/:id/opmerkingen/:child", auth, function (req, res, next) {
      let query = Topic.findById(req.params.id).opmerkingen.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.child);
      console.log(query);
      console.log()
      query.exec(function(err){
        if(err) {
          return next(err);
        }
      })
      .then(doc => {
        if(!doc) {
          return res.status(404).end();      
        }
      }).catch(err => next(err));
    });
```

Below you see how it looks in the database

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b4a2cc7c851630014f47971"
    },
    "name": "14/07/2018",
    "vraag": "proberen",
    "user": "dennis",
    "opmerkingen": [
        {
            "name": "datum juli",
            "user": "dennis",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5b4a2cd6c851630014f47972"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "datum",
            "user": "dennis",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5b4a2fb5479af40014a70ec8"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "date",
            "user": "dennis",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5b4a3225778dec0014ea1429"
            }
        }
    ],
    "__v": 3
    }
```